# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str,while parsing json

Tags: python, json

After submitting a request I have received the following json back:

```
{"type": [
{"ID": "all", "count": 1, "references": [
    { "id": "Boston,MA,02118", "text": "Boston,MA,02118", "val": "Boston,MA,02118", "type": 1 ,"zip": "02118","city": "Boston","state": "MA","lt": "42.3369","lg": "-71.0637","s": ""}
] }
] }
```

I captured the response in variable j and loaded it as follows,

```
l = json.loads(j)
```

Now I have:

```
>>> type(l)
<type 'dict'>
>>> l['type']['references']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyCharm\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`l['type']` gives you a list, not an object. So you have to access it like a list

```
l['type'][0]["references"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of the key `type` is a list. Try doing `type(l['type'])` to confirm.

To access that value you would need to use:

`l['type'][0]['references']`

which would give you another list.